# What are the ways in which placed towers can be moved while remaining active?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

On the Throne Room map, I noticed that as the boss advanced, he would push Slice N Dice Blockades back slowly as he advanced forward. The towers would remain active but just get pushed backward, eventually ending up in a little clump on the other side of the crystals.

Are there any other ways that towers can be moved while remaining active, particularly, can you move your own towers like that?

Comment: I noticed this as well. I'm pretty sure it's just a side effect of the boss collision, not any sort of "feature" that's purposefully meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cannot. This is something unique to the boss, I've noticed some ogres do it as well, but only on the second level.

The only way to move your towers (legitimately, there may be some bug/glitch I am unaware of) is to sell them and rebuild.

Comment: Point of note: If the tower has taken damage or has been upgraded, you will sell them at a loss. You won't get back what you've invested into the tower.

Comment: @Shaun You sell the tower at a loss under almost all circumstances. The only time a tower *isn't* sold at a loss is if you build it and sell it in the same build phase without upgrading it.

Comment: @StrixVaria I could be wrong, but I seem to remember selling a tower a wave later for the base cost.

Comment: @Shaun As soon as the combat phase begins, the amount you get for selling an unupgraded tower halves.

Comment: You can also use the Jester's "Move Tower" ability. I've never used it myself though.